# Why can't I select content with the instantiate argument in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

The following works fine,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-editable" constructor="EditableComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <div style="display: {{editing ? 'block' : 'none'}}">
          <content select=".editing"></content>
        </div>
        <div style="display: {{editing ? 'none' : 'block'}}">
          <content select=".normal"></content>
        </div>
        <script type="application/dart" src="xeditable.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
      </template>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

it grabs all the children within `x-editable` that have `.editing` and `.normal`, and displays them according to whether the bool `editing` is true or not.

However, the following does not work,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-editable" constructor="EditableComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <template instantiate="if editing">
          <content select=".editing"></content>
        </template>
        <template instantiate="if !editing">
          <content select=".normal"></content>
        </template>
        <script type="application/dart" src="xeditable.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
      </template>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

It did not grab any of the `.editing` or `.normal` children. Obviously, I am doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `<content>` does not work within nested template tags. It's annoying but there are workarounds. Your workaround of setting the display of a div seems to work well for your case. In other situations it may make more sense to split the component into multiple parts.

Comment: Can you show an example of splitting the component into parts?